# Comparing user input to a string in C

Tags: c

I am trying to see if the user inputs an "h" so that I can run another function, but for some reason, when I run the program, it states Segmentation Fault. Any help would be appreciated.

```
char checkh[] = "h";
char *checkInput;
printf("Enter input:");
scanf("%s", checkInput);

    if(strcmp(checkInput, checkh) == 0){
            helpMsg();
    }
```

Comment: No memory allocated for `checkInput`. You need an array. But don't use `scanf()` for obtaining user input, it's evil. Just declare a buffer (an array of `char`s), then call `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)`. But this is a duplicate a lot of times. I mean, hundreds of times. Why couldn't you spend a minute or two on searching for the solution of such a trivial error?

Comment: @H2CO3 everything you said I thumbs up except the `scanf` comment. You can protect from overrun it with a length-prefix : `%Ns`. Only important if you don't want to eat an entire line out of the stream, as `fgets()` will with a sufficient buffer. If that isn't important, `fgets()` is the defacto choice. =P

Comment: @WhozCraig True, and I know that, but IMHO it's even more evil. `scanf("%Ns")` does **not** NUL-terminate if the input is too long, so it seems safe but in fact it's unsafe. **Pretty please do not suggest its use.** And anyway, `scanf()` has unintuitive quirks that only make programming unnecessarily harder. No need for that.

Comment: @H2CO3 Like many things (...cough `strncpy()`...) its safe if you know what you're doing. If not, hell, even getting our of bed in the morning is a crapshoot. And who said this was supposed to be easy? Find that guy and throttle him, 'cause I think I got rooked =P

Comment: @WhozCraig lol, nope :P I mean: why make our lives deliberately harder if we can have nice, easy, simple and safe solutions? I honestly can't find a case where `fgets()` would be a worse choice than `scanf()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 well, going down that road, assuming you take care of the whitespace lead-in, token separation, etc, then even `fgets()` isn't the silver bullet since a line longer than your buffer won't buy you any more benefit than a properly formed N-1 `fread()` with a hard-set null-char. I don't suggest using `scanf()`, here or anywhere else. I suggest that if used properly, its ok. If not, like anything else, you roll the dice and take your chances. (and I use C++ and `std::getline()` or a `std::string` extraction, so for me its moot regardless, as you likely do too).

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah okay. Then I misunderstood you a bit. (And yes, `getline()` is something that always works, and in C++, I always use it.)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using simple by:

```
char choice;
scanf("%c",&choice);
if(choice=='h' || choice=='H')
{
    help();
}
```

Comment: Better yet, `choice = getchar();`.

Comment: +1 (and +1 to @H2CO3, see, we *do* concur on lots of stuff =P). And note, be careful if doing this in a loop, as the `%c` format specifier will *not* consume and ignore whitespace like string extraction will.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the comments are all talking about, I believe.  You have to allocate memory before using a `char *var` the way you are.

In your existing code, add the lines indicated, and you will not get the seg fault.

```
char checkh[] = "h";
char *checkInput;  
checkInput = malloc(10);//add this line;
printf("Enter input:");
scanf("%s", checkInput);

    if(strcmp(checkInput, checkh) == 0){
            helpMsg();
    }  
//some code  
free(checkInput);//add this line
```

Comment: This is a recipe for **undefined behavior** if the user enters more than nine characters. Either use `fgets()` (throwing H2CO3 his richly earned kudos), or properly limit the maximum string length in the format string.